# Mongodb $redact by comparing two fields in subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I've updated to Mongodb 2.6.1 and have attempted, unsuccessfully, to use the new [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend) aggregation function to solve a business problem. All the $redact examples I've come across evaluate against an external variable or static value.

I need to eliminate some resulting documents based on a value in a sibling subdocument. I believe $redact would be the way to do this, if possible, but like all technical challenges I'm sure there are several ways to resolve. I want to keep the document structure as is. I can eliminate the extra results in my application code, if needed, but would prefer the data come out of the database just right.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

**The collection**

`Location.id` is an int set in the application code and is only used to create a relationship between locations and rewards (a reward may only be valid at a few locations). The below doc has been pared down to focus on what important here.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53728b24e4749ce8ac3f31e7"),
    "name" : "Business name",
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Downtown Norfolk",
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "McDonald's Suffolk",
            "id" : 4
        }
    ],
    "rewards" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Reward for Downtown Norfolk Only",
            "locationIDs" : [3]
        }
    ]
}
```

**The query**

What I need to produce is a list of each reward and its applicable locations. I can use the below to get the full list of location/rewards...

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$rewards' },
  { $unwind:  '$locations' },                      
  { $project: { name: 1, rewards: 1, locations: 1 } }
  }    
])
```

**The query results**

The below basically joins all locations to all rewards. But this reward only applies to location.id = 3, not to 3 and 4, so I need to eliminate location.id = 4 from the results. I need to continue to use aggregation because the actual query (not shown here) includes $geoNear.

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53728b24e4749ce8ac3f31e7"),
            "name" : "Business name",
            "locations" : {
                "name" : "Downtown Norfolk",
                "id" : 3
            },
            "rewards" : {
                "name" : "Newport News Only Reward",
                "locationIDs" : [3]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53728b24e4749ce8ac3f31e7"),
            "name" : "Business name",
            "locations" : {
                "name" : "McDonald's Suffolk",
                "id" : 4
            },
            "rewards" : {
                "locationIDs" : [3]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**The query results I want**

What I'm trying to do is eliminate the last document from the above query results, where the locationIDs don't match (where locations.id = 4 is not in rewards.locationIDs = [3]). Below is what I would like to get back from Mongo.

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53728b24e4749ce8ac3f31e7"),
            "name" : "Business name",
            "locations" : {
                "name" : "Downtown Norfolk",
                "id" : 3
            },
            "rewards" : {
                "name" : "Newport News Only Reward",
                "locationIDs" : [ 
                    3
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure $redact would help. I suggest to use $cmp operator to compare values, like this:

```
db.ttt.aggregate({$unwind:"$locations"},
                 {$unwind:"$rewards"},
                 {$unwind:"$rewards.locationIDs"},
                 {$project:
                          {_id:1,
                           name:1,
                           locations:1,
                           rewards:1,
                           equality:{
                                     $cmp:['$locations.id','$rewards.locationIDs']
                                    }
                          }
                 },
                 {$match:{equality:0}})
```

It will exclude not matched documents, and then you need to group back

Comment: Bingo. I hadn't considered unwinding 'rewards.locationIDs'. Smart! That did the trick.